# Change compilator language

Tags: qt, compilation, mingw32

Mingw32-make when compiling spits out dir like Qt, but instead of "Vydání" which is czech for release (dont know how to change this either, maybe the reason is my windows is czech and i am not going to install english because of this, rest of QtCreator is in english except debug and release)it spits out VydßnÝ, which breaks use of Qt, because it cant send file to android device.

How can i fix this? I was trying setting system variable LANG to en_US, but it didnt help.

Thanks for your support.

Comment: Is it about build or the program code running?

Comment: i build it and it puts files into 2 different folders, so i cant run them. it cant install them into virtual android machine.
Output folder from compilator has different name, because it cant write "Vydání" so it writes "VydßnÝ" at the end of folder name and i dont know how to fix this

Comment: Why would you make your own names for Debug and Release? Use English for those. If the question was about internationalization, I could've answered it. But the question is about doing an unnecessary thing. I can tell how to make one Qt executable for different languages, though.

Comment: i cant change them. my os language is czech, but my qt language is set to english. but with this setup i have instead of "release" written "vydání" and it breaks building of program. all i want to know, how can i change it to english or fix it some way

Comment: The OS language is merely locale or what language it is configured to handle, say, error messages. Or tell me what kind of OS it is. There is no reason to substitute technical terms with native language. I myself am not a native English speaker, btw. The internationalization is a different problem in reality. The issue you present is kind of weird.

Comment: http://oi57.tinypic.com/2ql7laq.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with directory name which is misinterpreted by build tools.

Specify the build directory like that in English:
http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtcreator-2.4/creator-build-settings.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your support. Changing directory name fixed it.